# How to Uncheck A radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, dynamic-forms

I have two forms, one with a radio button that users must select to edit.

```
[form name="A"]
<li>[input type="radio" name="BookItem" value="1" /]</li>
<li>[input type="radio" name="BookItem" value="2" /]</li>
<li>[input type="radio" name="BookItem" value="3" /]</li>
[form]<p>
```

After "BookItem" is selected from form (A) I call the `$("#EditFormWrapper").load("callEditData.cfm? ID="+ID);` function to load the second form (B)

```
<div id="EditFormWrapper"><div></p>
<!---//  begin dynamic form generated by external file callEditData.cfm  //--->
[form id="editForm" name="B"]
<ul class="hourswrapper">
<li><input type="checkbox" id="TOR2Hours" class="TOR2Hours" name="TOR2Hours" value="AM2Hrs1" /> 2 Hours AM</li>
 <li><input type="checkbox" id="TOR2Hours" class="TOR2Hours" name="TOR2Hours" value="PM2Hrs1" /> 2 Hours PM</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" id="TOR2Hours" class="TOR2Hours" name="TOR2Hours" value="AM2Hrs2" /> 2 Hours AM</li>
 <li><input type="checkbox" id="TOR2Hours" class="TOR2Hours" name="TOR2Hours" value="PM2Hrs2" /> 2 Hours PM</li>
</ul>
[input type="image" src="images/submit-btn.gif" id="addBTN" name="addBTN" class="buttons" alt="SubmitRrequest" /]
[input type="image" src="images/cancel-btn.gif" id="editBTNcancel" name="editBTNcancel" class="buttons" alt="Cancel Request" /]
[/form]
<!---//  end dynamic form from external file //--->
```

I want to uncheck the radio button on form (A) when user click on cancel button (editBTNcancel) in form(B).

Here's my script:

```
$("#editBTNcancel").live("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#EditFormWrapper").slideUp("fast").empty();
    //$('.TOR2Hours').removeAttr('checked');
    $('.TOR2Hours').attr('checked', false);
});
```

I hope I clearly state my problem, any suggestion would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you post the HTML containing the radio buttons. `.removeAttr('checked')` and `.attr('checked', false)` both work for me. http://jsfiddle.net/JAEsd/ also, what browser you testing these on?

Comment: Please repost your code as HTML, not as BB code

Comment: `$(radio).attr('checked', false)` is correct and works for me. Are you sure you're selecting the right elements? I don't see `class="TOR2Hours"` in your radios.

Comment: For me only `.removeAttribute('checked')` works

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you want but you might try using a reset input.

```
<input type='reset' />
```

Comment: totaly agree, or as i answered not a control, but `reset` event

Comment: thank for your response, but the radio button is not in the same form so this wouldn't work.

Comment: @user281867: call `reset` for the form radio buttons are in. `document.getElementById("radiobuttonsform").reset();`

Comment: THANKS Vittore, this document.getElementById("radiobuttonsform").reset(); works!!!

Comment: Sorry this is 8 years late. If you are paying attention to clear HTML semantics, you *should* put your reset in the same form as the controls it resets. Saying "It's not in the same form" suggests your forms are put together in a confusing way. I get how you might have used the `<form>` elements to divide up form controls on your page, but you probably didn't need to and could have used `<fieldset>`, `<section>`, `<p>` or `<div>` instead. Or, perhaps you have different forms which point to different endpoints, in which case you can provide separate reset controls for each.

Answer (score 11):

you can access form like so ...

```
var exampleForm = document.forms['form_name'];
```

then loop through the form

```
for( var i=0; i<exampleForm.length; i++ ){
   alert( exampleForm[i].type );
}
```

you can test for checked like so ...

```
if( exampleForm[i].checked )
```

to deselect the checked radio button try ...

```
exampleForm[i].checked=false;
```

the final code would look like this ...

```
var exampleForm = document.forms['form_name'];
for( var i=0; i<exampleForm.length; i++ ){
   if( exampleForm[i].type ) == 'radio' && exampleForm[i].checked == true ){
       exampleForm[i].checked = false;
   }
}
```

Comment: Your first piece of code should say `document` instead of `documents`. Nice answer, though.

Comment: Is there any way to tell if a radio has been *deselected*? I've worked in frameworks so long... just realized that `onchange` is actually `onchangedtotrue`... If I had listeners on each radio in a group, in order to get the selected button, shouldn't all other listeners in that group fire off with `event.target.checked === false` each time a new one is selected? That's how checkboxes work, right?

Answer (score 3):

Seeing as this is pretty much the easiest DOM task there is and works in every scriptable browser, I suggest not using the jQuery methods for it:

```
$(".TOR2Hours")[0].checked = false;
```

The other thing that ocurs to me is whether your selector is correct. Did you mean to select a set of elements by class or should it be an ID selector?

Answer (score 1):

Your  selector is simply wrong.
If you want to uncheck the radio button from first form you should use `$('input[name="BookItem"]')` and not `$('.TOR2Hours')` :

`$("#editBTNcancel").on("click", function(event){
    $("#EditFormWrapper").slideUp("fast").empty();
    $('input[name="BookItem"]').attr('checked', false);
});`

As far as which method to use to uncheck radio buttons, The following 3 methods should all work:

1. `$('input[name="BookItem"]').attr('checked', false);`
2. `$('input[name="BookItem"]').removeAttr('checked');`
3. `$('input[name="BookItem"]').prop('checked', false);`

However, check out jQuery's docs on [jQuery prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) for the difference between `attr()` and `prop()`.

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered a great solution to this problem.

Assuming you have two radios that need to be able to be checked/unchecked, implement this code and change what's necessary:

```
var gift_click = 0;
    function HandleGiftClick() {
        if (document.getElementById('LeftPanelContent_giftDeed2').checked == true) {
            gift_click++;
            memorial_click = 0;
        }
        if (gift_click % 2 == 0) {document.getElementById('LeftPanelContent_giftDeed2').checked = false; }
    }
    var memorial_click = 0;
    function HandleMemorialClick() {          
        if (document.getElementById('LeftPanelContent_memorialDeed2').checked == true) {
            memorial_click++;
            gift_click = 0;
        }
        if (memorial_click % 2 == 0) { document.getElementById('LeftPanelContent_memorialDeed2').checked = false; }
    }
```

:) your welcome

Comment: Don't know WHY this answer was at -1. This is closer to an Acceptable answer because **it addresses the most difficult part of unchecking a radio input -- THE EVENT SEQUENCE**. Everyone should know the obvious `checked` property -- ACTUALLY, you might not even care about this, depending on what framework you're using. **The problem is** that when you receive an event -- say, a click -- when you uncheck the radio *it may always show `checked === true`*. This may be the most well thought out answer here, by far.

Answer (score 0):

I use this way to solve your problem in ASP.net, check this..

```
radioButton.InputAttributes["show"] = "false"; 
string clickJs = " if(this.show =='true'){this.show ='false'; this.checked = false;}else{this.show='true'; this.checked = true;};";  

radioButton.Attributes["onClick"] = clickJs;
```

**In asp.net, you can use this way to add an attribute. And you can also to add an attribute manually to the radioButton, and do the function(clickJs) to change the ckecked attributes!!!**

Answer (score 0):

It always works, unless you set debug break points.

```
var auswahl_dachaufbau = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"][name="dachart"]');
// Damit man Radio-Buttons auch unchecked machen kann

Array.prototype.forEach.call(auswahl_dachaufbau, function(rd) {
    // Event-Listener für Radio-Buttons 
    rd.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
        let id = e.target.id;
        if (this.checked) {
            // Das Setzen der onclick-function auf diese Weise ist dafür da, damit man
            // Radio-Buttons auch unchecked machen kann ohne einen neuen Radio-Button auszuwählen
            // Seltsamerweise ist das nicht möglich ohne weiteres
            this.onclick = function() {
                this.checked = false;
            }
        } else {
            this.onclick = null;
        }
    });
});
```

It does not work when you set debug break points.