# jQuery's attr() method behavior

Tags: jquery

<sup>*This is not a **‘** [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr) vs [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop) **’** question.*</sup>

Consider having this so simple web form:

```
<form action="/">
    <input type="radio" name="type" value="1" checked>
    <input type="radio" name="type" value="2" >
    <input type="radio" name="type" value="3" >
    <input type="radio" name="type" value="4" >
    <button type="submit"> Submit </button>
</form>
```

The very first radio button has `checked` attribute as its default, and opening this web form brings up a well known picture:

[image]

Within a written jQuery script file, I'm trying to check a radio button - however it could be done using `prop()` in a right and headache-less way, I went with `attr()`.

Using browser's console, I'm able to check results immediately:

[image]

[image]

But I know I should uncheck all inputs before checking desired one to expect the correct result:

[image]

[image]

The argue begins here, when repeating the first step:

[image]

[image]

My question is why this happens? No check mark in radio button and in regards no value in server side.

Comment: Post your jQuery code

Comment: @AnkurBhadania This simple example is a real example with so given codes. Yet there is no `.js` file.

Comment: What version jQuery are you using?

Comment: @putvande jQuery v1.12.1

Comment: I wonder if this is a console specific.  ie. is this replicable if run as normal javascript?  Either way I am looking forward to an answer.  Upvoted

Comment: Not related to console: https://jsfiddle.net/00a0qoy1/

Comment: The code, for anyone who wants to test it: https://jsfiddle.net/7obwhush/

Comment: works as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/ybocww3f/2/ ? or what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @caramba not if you use an older version of jQuery.

Comment: and you went trough all those Q/A ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589052/how-to-uncheck-a-radio-button http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10876953/how-to-make-a-radio-button-unchecked-by-clicking-it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17120576/how-to-uncheck-checked-radio-button http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/setting-checked-for-a-checkbox-with-jquery http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/setting-checked-for-a-checkbox-with-jquery http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117538/how-to-uncheck-a-radio-button

Comment: or vanilla javascript if jQuery want do the trick:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554116/how-to-clear-radio-button-in-javascript

Comment: @caramba Those are not covering same issue but I'm going to post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is jQuery version specific. It's not a bug at all and wasn't shipped with jQuery v3 alpha release either.

However later, from jQuery v3 beta release, `removeAttr()` was changed a little.

In jQuery **< 3.***, `removeAttr()` method sets dynamic/current state to false:

```
// Set corresponding property to false
if ( getSetInput && getSetAttribute || !ruseDefault.test( name ) ) {
    elem[ propName ] = false;
```

And in ther other side `attr()` only sets the default state (not current state). But in jQuery **>= 3.0**, we don't see these lines anymore.

In all versions except v3.* (> final and beta releases), we can't expect from these two lines to check a radio button:

```
$('input[name="type"]').removeAttr('checked');
$('input[value="3"]').attr('checked', true);
```

But these three lines work alongside each other:

```
$('input[name="type"]').removeAttr('checked');
$('input[value="3"]').attr('checked', true);
$('input[value="3"]').prop('checked', true);
```

Or much more simpler:

```
$('input[name="type"]').removeAttr('checked');
$('input[value="3"]').prop('checked', true);
```

(But be aware that some javascript codes may check for attributes rather than properties. So you have to do an extra `.atrr()`)

Also in earlier versions it's much better not to use `removeAttr()` at all but only `attr()` like so:

```
$('input[name="type"]:checked').attr('checked', false);
$('input[type="3"]').attr('checked', true);
```

This behavior change of `removeAttr()` is discussed on [Github](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/1759) as well.

Thanks to those who commented on this issue.